# How can i create a timer to count 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

My objective is when my powerball collides with the player’s ship it boosts the scrolling speed of the backgrounds and the speed of the enemy ships for 10seconds. I have came up with some code to do this but when I run the game and hit a powerball the background and enemy ships only speed up for a 2-3 seconds instead of 10.

idk what I'm doing wrong so could anyone please help me out?
this is what I have so far:

```
// Do the collision bewtween the player and the powerball
for (int i = 0; i < powerballs.Count; i++)
{
    rectangle3 = new Rectangle((int)powerballs[i].Position.X,
        (int)powerballs[i].Position.Y,
        powerballs[i].Width,
        powerballs[i].Height);

    // Determine if the two objects collided with each other
    if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle3))
    {
        boost = true;
        powerballs[i].Active = false;
    }
    else
        boost = false;

    float elasped = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    timer -= elasped;
    if (boost == true && timer < 10f)
    {                   
            for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Count; j++)
            {
                // Increased enemy speed variable
                float newEnemySpeed = 30f;

                // Setting increased speed to each enemy in the list 
                enemies[j].SetNewMoveSpeed(newEnemySpeed);
            }
            //Increased Background speed variables
            int newBackgroundSpeed1 = -5;
            int newBackgroundSpeed2 = -10;

            // Setting increased Background speed
            bgLayer1.SetNewSpeed(newBackgroundSpeed1);
            bgLayer2.SetNewSpeed(newBackgroundSpeed2);;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < enemies.Count; k++)
        {
            // Set emeny speed back to normal
            enemies[k].SetNewMoveSpeed(6f);
        }
        // Set background speed back to normal
        bgLayer1.SetNewSpeed(-1);
        bgLayer2.SetNewSpeed(-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you reset your timer? What value do you set your timer to? Seems like you should set timer to 10f whenever player hits the powerup, and change timer<10f to timer>0

Comment: instead of counting to exactly 10 you can just base it off of the iterations of the game loop.  start counting, when the timer is greater than 10 then stop

Answer (score 2):

Something like this comes to mind (there are several other ways to do this). As soon as the powerball collides, you boost the speed. You would implement an ITimerDispatchableEvent which can set the speed back to normal.

```
class Timer {
    private double _time;
    private readonly IList<ITimerDispatchableEvent> _events;

    public Timer(double currentTime) {
      _time = currentTime
    }

    // Update this on each call back during the main loop
    public void Update(double deltaTime) {
        _time += deltaTime;
        Dispatch();
    }

    private void Dispatch() {
        // Iterate events
        // if event.FireTime <= _time
        //   event.Fire();
    }

    public void AddEvent(ITimerDispatchableEvent event) {
        _events.add(event);
    }
}

public interface ITimerDispatchableEvent {
    // the absolute time to fire. E.g. if we want to fire in 10seconds
    // this will be Timer._time += 10 (assuming deltaTime is in seconds)
    double FireTime { get; }
    void Fire();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float elasped = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    timer -= elasped;`

Why don't you try a `TimeSpan` object?

```
/**Class Attributes**/
TimeSpan t;
/**End**/
for (int i = 0; i < powerballs.Count; i++)
{
    rectangle3 = new Rectangle((int)powerballs[i].Position.X,
        (int)powerballs[i].Position.Y,
        powerballs[i].Width,
        powerballs[i].Height);

    // Determine if the two objects collided with each other
    if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle3))
    {
        boost = true;
        powerballs[i].Active = false;

        //reset timer if collide, and intanciate them the first time\\
        t = new TimeSpan();
    }
    else
    {
        boost = false;
    }
    if (boost == true && t.Milliseconds <= 10000)
    {                   
            for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Count; j++)
            {
                // Increased enemy speed variable
                float newEnemySpeed = 30f;

                // Setting increased speed to each enemy in the list 
                enemies[j].SetNewMoveSpeed(newEnemySpeed);
            }
            //Increased Background speed variables
            int newBackgroundSpeed1 = -5;
            int newBackgroundSpeed2 = -10;

            // Setting increased Background speed
            bgLayer1.SetNewSpeed(newBackgroundSpeed1);
            bgLayer2.SetNewSpeed(newBackgroundSpeed2);;

            //increment Timer with the gameTime\\
            t+=gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < enemies.Count; k++)
        {
            // Set emeny speed back to normal
            enemies[k].SetNewMoveSpeed(6f);
        }
        // Set background speed back to normal
        bgLayer1.SetNewSpeed(-1);
        bgLayer2.SetNewSpeed(-2);
    }
}
```

For more check out [the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: Thank to jeroen Bollen

Answer (score -2):

Here is code to create a 10 second timer:

```
long startTicks = System.Environment.TickCount;
            long tenSeconds = 10000;
            while (ticksElapsed > tenSeconds)
            {
                long ticksElapsed = System.Environment.TickCount - startTicks;

            }
```

This will run for 10 seconds and you can do something in the while loop for that time as well if needed.

Comment: Apologies this would sleep the entire game. I misunderstood your question, i thought you wanted to pause the game for 10 seconds. I'll edit with a better answer now

Comment: In fact it won't sleep anything because it can't even compile (ticksElapsed defined inside the loop but previously used just above), and even if we get ticksElapsed definition out of the loop it still doesn't do anything...